# How to find out the ECDSA private key perfix version for Altcoins?

Tags: private-key, ecdsa

I want to create a paperwallet for an altcoin ([Protoshares](http://protoshares.net/)).

I know the public key version byte is `0x38` (56) and the addresses start with `P...`

But how do I find out the ECDSA private key prefix? For bitcoin it's `0x80`, for litecoin it's `0xb0`.

The Protoshares private keys start with `7...` if that helps. Any idea where to look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the private key. It's probably expressed in base-58 encoding, so you just have to translate the number into base-16. The prefix is there in hexadecimal form.

To convert a base58 number to hex, check [etotheipi's code](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=29140.msg370477#msg370477). Based on it:

```
b58_digits = '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def base58_to_hex(b58str):
  n = 0
  for s in b58str:
    n *= 58
    digit = b58_digits.index(s)
    n += digit
  return hex(n)
```